# JSON log and PUT to cloud

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a javascript function which generates JSON data at every 2 second and then PUT it to a cloud. Now I don't want to POST in realtime. rather I want to log this data in a buffer and say after n number of data log I will PUT to cloud.

Now JSON data is passed through `var fromDatan`. JSON data format is

```
{"values": [ { "at": "2014-08-17T12:00:00Z", "value": "15" }]}
```

This is a single instance which is passing through say `var fromDatan` and being PUT in cloud.

Now I want to log say n number of JSON data. ie.

```
{ "values": [ { "at": "2014-08-17T12:00:00Z", "value": "15" }, { "at": "2014-08-18T12:00:00Z", "value": "20" }, { "at": "2014-08-19T12:00:00Z", "value": "25" } ] }
```

And then I will PUT to cloud. This is my PUT code:

```
$.ajax({
                url: "https://abcd.com",
                headers: {
                    "X-API-KEY": "23dq3dq3ddbb16a7956e6f7a",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                type: "PUT",
                data: fromDatan,
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(fromData, status, jqXHR) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(fromData));
                },

                error: function(jqXHR, status) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                }
                });
```

So please let me know how to do this.

Comment: so push the data to the array and send it up.....what is the issue?

Comment: @epascarello can you show me how to push JSON format data? I don't know much

Comment: Look into `JSON.stringify(fromDatan)`

Comment: I am not getting you, What to look? this is stringifying JSON.